# Divi Theme: Portfolio Module: Project title display in overlay

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I'm using the Divi Wordpress theme for my portfolio site.

I plan on using the filterable portfolio module to display my work. Current state of my website: http://anti-mogul.com.

I saw this example (below), I really like how the titles of each project display over the thumbnail when hovering. I'd like to add this functionality to the portfolio section on my site.

Example:
http://doers.sg/work/

I've been able to change a lot of the other features through CSS overrides - but this seems to be more of a structural thing.

From looking at the differences between the example site and my own - the builder of the example site has managed to move the h2 containing the title into the span class "et_overlay" above it.

If anybody could suggest a solution for this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.et_pb_portfolio_item{
    position: relative;
}
.et_pb_portfolio_item h2{ 
    position: absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:2%;
    display:none;
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }
.et_pb_portfolio_item:hover h2{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="post-546" class="et_pb_portfolio_item et_pb_grid_item project_category_web post-546 project type-project status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry project_category-web first_in_row" style="display: block;">
          <a href="http://anti-mogul.com/project/project_8/">
             <span class="et_portfolio_image">
              <img src="http://anti-mogul.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/gallery-5.jpg" alt="Project_8" height="284" width="400">      <span class="et_overlay"></span>       </span>
            </a>
    
         <h2><a href="http://anti-mogul.com/project/project_8/">Project_8</a></h2>
    
    
    </div>
```

you can also add transform effects on hover as per your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. how would you suggest implementing that solution - keeping in mind the nature of the divi theme and modules?

Comment: i have edited the above code according to your themes div structure, you don not need to change the html just update the code in your style.css or custom css for adding above hovering effects.

Comment: Thank you senpai - that's sorted out everything :)

Comment: welcome! :) can you please also upvote if it is helpful for you.